# Prevent multiple calls to Android Service OnStart() from Start() -ing same Thread over again (Xamarin)

Tags: android, multithreading, xamarin, service

The code example is from an application which uses a Service to perform some tasks on a Thread dedicated to that Service. When the Android device changes orientation and the MainActivity recreates itself it calls the Service's OnCreate() again which in turn creates another Thread. The thread is meant to run infinately and this creates multiple Threads which causes a problem.

```
public class myService: Service 
{
    Java.Lang.Thread serviceThread;

    public override OnCreate() 
    {
        serviceThread = new Java.Lang.Thread(infiniteLoop);

        if(serviceThread.GetState != "RUNNABLE") 
        {
            serviceThread.Start();
        }
    }   
}
```

I have tried to make this global but the compiler disagrees with the infiniteLoop:

```
Java.Lang.Thread serviceThread = new Java.Lang.Thread(infiniteLoop);
```

I have tried many things but I completely run out of ideas. Thought I should get some help.

Comment: Have you tried using a application variabel to see if the service is running or not?

Comment: @JordyDieltjens Could you tell me how can I check this please?

Comment: In my answer I showed how to create an application variabele and how to use this. But I think York Shen his answer is a lot better than mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea would be a global bool to check if the service already started or not:

```
   public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static bool ThreadStarted;
    static GlobalVariables()
      {
         ThreadStarted=false;

      }


}
```

And than in your Oncreate:

```
public class myService: Service 
{
    Java.Lang.Thread serviceThread;

    public override OnCreate() 
    {
        serviceThread = new Java.Lang.Thread(infiniteLoop);

        if(serviceThread.GetState != "RUNNABLE" && !GlobalVariables.ThreadStarted) 
        {
GlobalVariables.ThreadStarted = true;
            serviceThread.Start();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize but my problem was due to another factor. I find both the suggestions correct but I'll take this solution since its more specific to the problem and might help with Threads in other situations.

Answer (score 2):

> When the Android device changes orientation and the MainActivity recreates itself it calls the Service's OnCreate() again

Add [ConfigurationChanges](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/handling_rotation/#Preventing_Activity_Restart) attribute like this :

```
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation|ConfigChanges.ScreenSize
```

You could prevent the `Activity` to be recreated when the device changes orientation, then your `Service`'s `OnCreate()` wont be call again.